# Cannot get specific data off the internet

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am encountering a problem in my Android application where I get all the content on the page, but I only want part of it. Here is part of my code:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String text1 = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD")) {          
            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/finance/market_news?ei=_FLfUbD4JrG90QGf6wE").get();
                String body = doc.body().text();
                textView1.setText(body);

            } catch (IOException e) {


        }
```

Here is what I am getting in my application:

http://oi41.tinypic.com/343kmwx.jpg

The stuff I want in my application starts from "An Ethiopian Airlines........ on 767 Dreamliner fire.

What do I need to do? I am not experienced in CSS, Javascript, or HTML. I have checked all over google too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code. This will work for this specific case. However you might want to add some end point or tailor your start point so that it will work with the general case.

```
String [] words = body.split(" ");
int startPlace = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< words.length; i++){
    if(words[i].equals("Ethiopian")){
        startPlace = i-1; //Because of the "An" word before
    }
}
String displayText = ""; // so += will work
for(int i = startPlace; i<words.length; i++){
    displayText += words[i]+" ";
}
//Set the text to your textview.
TextView contentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentTextView);
contentTextView.setText(displayText);
```

Comment: what is i in words.Length() mean?

Comment: it means that you will initialize the for loop with int i = 0 and you will keep incrementing i as long as i is less than the size of the words array. Just to make sure you will loop through all the words in the array.

Then once you have found the starting position, in this case when you find the wortd Ethiopian. You will make another loop which you initialize at that start position and you will keep going until you have reached the end of the word array. That ensures you have added all the words that came after your starting position to the displayText.

You can also add an endpoint if u like

Comment: No, I am asking what does "i in words.Length()" mean.  You are also missing WAY to much punctuation in the code.  Please revise your answer.

Comment: I edited the answer, this is working code for my Android device. In my case I used "body" as a String containing the text instead of fetching it off the internet.